# How to calculate the result of items that each multiply and add onto themselves

Tags: c

Say I have 10 items. I send these 10 items out into the world, and each of these 10 each get another 10 for itself.

This is not Fibonacci, which would be replicated into code as:

```
int fibonacci(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2);
}

int main() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t\n", fibonacci(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. How can I approach this in **C** up to the **7th** cycle
2. This seems to be something in statistics. What topic should I be researching.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I think you might be looking for [geometric prgression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it's not quite a geometric progression, because you still have the items you first started with.   It's more like `1 + 10 + ...`

Comment: @Alnitak That article also shows the formula for the partial sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: @Alnitak I removed that last part: "; *I am a self taught programmer, so no math, nor statistics background". I put it up in case it was an obvious question. I am interested in math.

Comment: 1 + 10 + 100 + ... is the (partial) sum of a geometric progression. I guess that's what the OP actually wants, but the problem description isn't exactly clear.

Comment: I am not sure I understand - what is your expected output for the 3th cycle? 111?

Comment: Please don't spam programming language tags. You should already know that this can bring negative attention to your question, attention that you (and we) don't want.

Comment: At the end of the first 'out and back' cycle, do you have 100 or 110 items in circulation?  Either could be a valid interpetation; the results over 7 cycles are quite different, though (since they're different after one, and the difference magifies itself on each cycle).

Comment: Khan Academy has a unit on this in their Algebra II course. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/sequences-and-series (edit: It's also in precalculus. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/seq-induction I don't remember what the difference between them is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to want the (partial) sum of a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), a*r^n with `a == 1` and `r == 10`.

I wouldn't even bother with recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

double partial_sum(double a, double r, size_t n) {
    double x = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        x += pow(r, i);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: There's also a formula without a summation, so the loop is unnecessary. [`a(1 - r^n) / (1 - r)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `fibonacci`, I understood your question as 
`How to handle a recursion-tree with a degree of 10?`
(Each recursion-step creates 10 new instances)

You can implement this in the same way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fibonacci(int i) {
    if (i <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    }    

    int result = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        result += fibonacci(i - j); //create 10 new instances in each call
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t\n", fibonacci(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: The depth of the tree does not grow with the degree, hence the required stack-size remains the same.